# Matplotlib -3D data visualization

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

[here is example of one txt file](http://www.filedropper.com/d401)

My experiment measurements are in several txt files (in reality I will have hundreds of files, but to demonstrate the idea of plotting, here I only list out 3 files, they are d_401.txt, d_402.txt, d_403.txt) each file has 4 columns & 256 rows of data. (only the first & forth column are the data I need for x and z)

I want to plot a 3D surface plot/or contour plot out of these files. In My 3D plot, x-axis is universally the 1st column data from each file, z-axis is the 4th column data from each file (z value also needs to be color-coded in gradient), and finally y-axis is "line-up in y direction" of all the x-z values plot from these three files.

How to generate the python code for this plot? I'm especially confused how to assign the matrix Z, would greatly appreciate if somebody could help me on this issue...I need to have the figure plotted soon.

I attached my pre-mature (supposedly full of error code)

Thanks a million!!!

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

z_txt = np.array(['d_401.txt', 'd_402.txt', 'd_403.txt'])

zarray = np.zeros([z_txt.size])
y = np.arange(3)
x = np.zeros(256)
Z = np.zeros((len(y),len(x)))


for i in range(z_txt.size):
    zarray[i] = np.loadtxt(z_txt[i])
    x[i] = zarray[i,0]
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    Z[i] = zarray[i,3]
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.magma, shade=True, lw=3)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please select a better describing title for your question, and leave out "urgent".

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: Where are the files? [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: So your points are`(x1,401,z11), (x2,401,z12), ..., (x1,402,z21), (x2,402,z22), ...` etc etc and you can guarantee the, in all the files, the `x1, x2, ...` sequence is the same?

Answer (score 0):

The following in the hypotesis that all the files contain the same vector of *x* …

```
In [146]: import numpy as np
     ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     ...: from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable as sm
     ...: from glob import glob
     ...: 
     ...: # create fake data and put it in files
     ...: x0, y0 = np.arange(11.0), np.arange(3)+1.0
     ...: z0 = x0+y0[:,None]
     ...: for i in range(3):
     ...:     with open('delendo%d'%(i+1), 'w') as out:
     ...:         for x0z0 in zip(x0, x0+x0, x0-x0, z0[i]):
     ...:             print(*x0z0, sep='\t', file=out)
     ...: 
     ...: # sorted list of "interesting" files
     ...: files = sorted(glob('delendo*'))
     ...: 
     ...: # read the matrix of z values
     ...: Z = np.array([np.loadtxt(f, usecols=3) for f in files])
     ...: # read the vector of x values (the same for all files, I hope so!)
     ...: x = np.loadtxt(files[0], usecols=0)
     ...: # we have as many y's as rows in Z, and we count from 1
     ...: y = np.arange(Z.shape[0])+1
     ...: 
     ...: # prepare for a 3D plot and plot as a surface
     ...: fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=1,
     ...:                        subplot_kw={"projection" : "3d"})
     ...: surf = ax.plot_surface(*np.meshgrid(x,y), Z, cmap='magma')
     ...: norm = plt.Normalize(*surf.get_clim())
     ...: plt.colorbar(sm(norm=norm, cmap='magma'))
     ...: plt.show()
```

[image]

---

#### Addendum

*to address some questions raised in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68363979/matplotlib-3d-data-visualization/68482117?noredirect=1#comment121056169_68482117) from OP*

You ask about the `*sequence` operator. It is the *unpack* operator, that can be used either in an assignment or in an expression. Let's see

```
>>> tup = (1,2,3,4,5)
>>> a = tup ; print(a)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> a, b = tup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

But if you use the unpack operator

```
>>> a, *b = tup ; print(a, b)
1 [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Python understand that `b` is a sequence and stores in this sequence the *remaining* elements of `tup` — incidentally, `b` is a list not a tuple.

The unpack operator can be used in the middle of a left member, but just once because Python assign to the starred item *what is left*, and two starred items lead to ambiguity.

```
>>> a,*b, c = tup ; print(a, b, c)
1 [2, 3, 4] 5
>>> a,*b, *c = tup ; print(a, b, c)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: multiple starred expressions in assignment
```

Now, let's see the unpack operator at work in an expression

```
>>> print(*b)
2 3 4
```

using the starred syntax the list is unpacked, it's like

```
>>> print(b[0], b[1], b[2])
2 3 4
```

Now, coming to your question, you have already used unpacking in your code. even if you possibly was not aware of it…

```
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
```

Coming to my code

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(*np.meshgrid(x,y), Z, cmap='magma')
```

at this point it should be clear, we are *unpacking* what is returned by `meshgrid`, it's like `X, Y = meshgrid(...) ; surf = ...(X, Y, Z, ...)` with the (small) advantage that the grid arrays (`X, Y`) are not referenced and the memory they use can be immediately given back to the interpreter.

With respect to your last point, to create a colorbar Matplotlib needs what is called a scalar mappable (s.m.) and `plt.colorbar` can check the active Axes to see if there is a s.m. hanging around.
Many Artists (the software agents that draw into the Axes) like e.g., `imshow` create a s.m. and all is well, but `plot_surface` won't, so the poor programmer has to provide a hand-made s.m. to `colorbar`.
To specify a s.m. we need ① a norm and ② a colormap.
The norm is the default, i.e., `plt.Normalize`, we need the limits of `Z` and these are the value of `surf.get_clim()`, again I used the starred syntax to unpack the two values.

The length of this explanation is a justification for having it omitted in the first place…

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes, the X-axis is actually the first column in the data files, and they are all pre-determined as a series of evenly spaced numbers. Now I basically figured out the "data sorting" part, and I'm quite interested in your code of plotting.
Such as, 
surf = ax.plot_surface(*np.meshgrid(x,y), Z, cmap='magma')
norm = plt.Normalize(*surf.get_clim())
They looks quite sophisticated high level of coding, I'm not so experienced in Python yet, could you let me know what is * means/do here?

Comment: @maggie I will edit the answer to address your concerns, just a few minutes...

Comment: wow...thanks a lot, this is the most informative answer I've ever got, really appreciated the efforts! I will put on my naïve version of code down below, to reflect my thought-process over this problem (actually plotting out the data is just the first step), and you probably will notice how "basic-level" my coding experience is..lol

Comment: @ghoffi  I upload my code (somehow it went up above your answers..) to plotting these data in a 3d version. But that's actually the first step in my problem....the next thing I need to do is, performing Fast Fourier Transform(FFT) along the straight line of the taken data (thus would be along Y-axis direction), so I'm still struggling on that. Do you have any suggestions on FFT in terms of "coding structure" (Do I need another for loop to do FFT on each Y value...?)

Comment: @Maggie You asked about some details of my answer that were unclear to you, I tried to clarify. Now it's different, it's a different question… if you have a different question, please post a different question,  this is how it works on this site,